# How to assign a value into the href of an anchor using HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

```
<a href="{seolink module='listings' method='view' data=$item}">{$item.output_name}</a>
```

Could anyone kindly explain what exactly happening there.
I got that it is passing $item to the view method of a listings module and what is that seolink.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I could have tried

```
<a href = "<?php echo base_url();?>/module/function_name"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem!
I have a Virtual host and using the laragon instead of Xampp. I am working with HMVC Codeigniter and I have defined the base_url in config.php as: hmvc.test. It is working perfectly for functions. When I create a php anchor or a href tag it redirect me to 127.0.0.1:

```
<?php echo anchor('tasks/create', '<p>Create New Task</p>'); ?>
OR
<a href="<?php echo base_url('tasks/two_col_template'); ?>">Create New Task</a>
OR
<a href="<?= base_url('tasks/two_col_template'); ?>">Create New Task</a>
```

But when I remove echo before base_url() it works fine.

```
<a href="<?php base_url(); ?>/tasks/two_col_template"> create Task</a>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why it is redirecting me to 127.0.0.1/Modules/Controller

Comment: Avoid using answers to ask questions.Use comments or ask a new question yourself...

Comment: I am not able to add comments for this question. Any way will try that in the future.